# Graph Excel REST API - Azure AD 2.0 Endpoint - Is OneDrive Personal Supported?

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I would like to access/manipulate Excel workbooks stored in OneDrive Personal using the Microsoft Graph REST API. 
I am able to access/manipulate Excel workbooks stored in OneDrive for Business.

I am able to authenticate my OneDrive Personal account (get access tokens, permission scopes, etc.) and I am able to do other (non-Excel-related) Graph REST operations, such as view file properties.

The Microsoft Graph Explorer https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer# only supports OneDrive for Business (not OneDrive Personal).

Here https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/excel, it says "…read and modify Excel workbooks stored in OneDrive, SharePoint, or other supported storage platforms".  Could they really mean "OneDrive for Business"?

When I try to access anything Excel-workbook-related (on OneDrive Personal), such as:

```
POST /{version}/me/drive/items/01CYZLFJGUJ7JHBSZDFZFL25KSZGQTVAUN/workbook/createSession
```

It always returns MethodNotAllowed:

```
{"error": {"code": "MethodNotAllowed","message": "Method not allowed.","innerError": { "request-id": "9c1d81ec-4300-4e8b-b453-82cd6caca00e", "date": "2016-10-19T01:25:20"} } }
```

I tried {version} v1.0 and beta.

Does the Graph Excel REST API support OneDrive Personal?  If not, when might it?  I can't find any documentation on this.
I realize Graph just recently started supporting OneDrive Personal via Azure AD 2.0 Endpoint, so perhaps there's just a delay in supporting Excel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functionality to access Excel REST API on workbooks in OneDrive personal is not available at the moment. We are working on enabling this in the near future.

Comment: do we have any tentative dates for enabling the Excel API for Office 365 Personal Subscription.

Comment: Support for this feature should arrive in the next 3-4 weeks.

Comment: @SudhiRamamurthy it's 2020, and this support isn't there yet https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: The OneDrive personal support is not yet available. The team is prioritizing the enterprise scenarios, stability, etc. For now, REST support for Excel is limited to enterprise accounts only.

Comment: I noticed that as of Mar-2021, the [beta version documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-beta) no longer specifically calls out OD for Business. @SudhiRamamurthy does this mean personal OD is now supported (in beta)?