# how to access Excel API through Graph Explorer with personal account

Tags: excel, api, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to access the Excel Api using office 365 personal account through [microsoft graph explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer#/). But it is not working. we tried this in graph explorer after login in with office 365 personal account

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items

Please suggest how to get this working.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121236/graph-excel-rest-api-azure-ad-2-0-endpoint-is-onedrive-personal-supported

Answer (score 2):

Excel REST API is not supported for consumer accounts at this point in time, but we do have this on our roadmap and hope to enable it soon.

Comment: please provide ballpark timeframe for when Excel REST API may be enabled for OneDrive consumer accounts.

Comment: "Soon" happened to not happen for 4 years already. It's year 2020, and there is still no support for Excel API for Personal accounts.