# Requests to Excel Microsoft Graph API for Personal vs Organizational Accounts

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using the Microsoft Graph API to get a workbook on a user's behalf. I want this scenario to work for both personal and organizational accounts. I am using the following request, which works for organizational accounts but not personal accounts:

```
GET /v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook
Authorization: Bearer {token}
```

Response:

```
"error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Resource not found.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "1b589c8b-1f65-4cf5-8429-5917cd6695f2",
      "date": "2017-02-14T20:13:08"
    }
```

The following request works fine for both personal and organizational accounts:

```
GET /v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}
Authorization: Bearer {token}
```

I see that OneDrive Personal accounts are reportedly not supported as of November 2016 ([Graph Excel REST API - Azure AD 2.0 Endpoint - Is OneDrive Personal Supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40121236/graph-excel-rest-api-azure-ad-2-0-endpoint-is-onedrive-personal-supported)). When is this going to be enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have a concrete release timeline yet but we are actively working on enabling the Excel REST API on consumer accounts.